# Quiero implementar el sort al hacer click en la cabecera de un datagridview desde LinQ

Tags: c#, windows-forms, linq

Especifico mejor lo que tengo para ver si puedes ayudarme amigo:
Tengo una clase DUsuario:

```
    public List<EUsuario> GrillaConsulta()
    {
      using (ContaAITEntities bdDatos = new ContaAITEntities())
      {
        List<EUsuario> Consulta = (from e in bdDatos.Usuario
                       orderby e.Cod_Usuario
                       select new EUsuario
                       {
                           Cod_Usuario = e.Cod_Usuario,
                           Nom_Usuario = e.Nom_Usuario,
                           Doc_Usuario = e.Doc_usuario,
                               Estado = e.Estado == "A" ? "Activo" : "Inactivo"
                       }).ToList();
        return Consulta;                                           
       }
    }
```

Como es anonima cree la clase EUsuario:

```
    namespace ContaAIT.Entidades
    {
        // Para la Grilla de Usuario
        public class EUsuario
        {
            public string Cod_Usuario { get; set; }
            public string Nom_Usuario { get; set; }
            public string Doc_Usuario { get; set; }
            public string Estado { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

En el Load de mi formulario llamo al metodo CargaGrilla()
Este es mi metodo CargaGrilla:

```
        try
        {
            dgvUsuario.DataSource = Usuario.GrillaConsulta();

            if (dgvUsuario.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                lblDatosNoEncontrados.Visible = false;
                dgvUsuario.Columns["Cod_Usuario"].HeaderText = "Código";
                dgvUsuario.Columns["Nom_Usuario"].HeaderText = "Nombre del Usuario";
                dgvUsuario.Columns["Doc_Usuario"].HeaderText = "Documento del Usuario";
                dgvUsuario.Columns["Estado"].HeaderText = "Estado";
                dgvUsuario.Sort(dgvUsuario.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            }
            else
            {
                lblDatosNoEncontrados.Visible = true;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Libreria.MensajeErrorGrave("Error : " + ex.Message, "ContaAIT");
        }
```

Justo cargando este linea me da el error:

```
dgvUsuario.Sort(dgvUsuario.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
```

Para que se pueda ordenar, un control DataGridView debe estar enlazado a un objeto IBindingList

Comment: Porqué pones eso en el Load, no era cuando dieras clic en el encabezado de una columana

Comment: Ya tu método GrillaConsulta tiene un orderby por el codigo

Comment: Por tanto cuando se cargue la información en el grid ya se ordenará , me parece que en el Load no debes usar el método Sort

Comment: Úsalo cuando des clic en el encabezado de alguna columna

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: Para poder usar `DataGridView.Sort` necesitas que su source sea un `DataView` o un `BindingSource`. Prueba a meter tus datos en un `DataTable` y asignaselo al `DataGridView`

Comment: Por otro lado..si ya estas ordenando en GrillaConsulta..para que quieres llamar a Sort?

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale? – Juan Carlos Guibovich este es el mensaje "Para que se pueda ordenar, un control DataGridView debe estar enlazado a un objeto IBindingList"

Comment: Pikon - Amigo quiero que por cada columna de mi grilla se pueda ordenar, código, nombre, documento, estado.. es por eso que lo necesito

Comment: Pikon - Amigo como haría esto "Para poder usar DataGridView.Sort necesitas que su source sea un DataView o un BindingSource. Prueba a meter tus datos en un DataTable y asignaselo al DataGridView"

Comment: Esta instrucción permite dgvUsuario.Sort(dgvUsuario.Columns["codigo"], ListSortDirection.Ascending); dgvUsuario.Sort(dgvUsuario.Columns["nombre"], ListSortDirection.Ascending); crear para cada header una flecha que si la persona hace clic en el header ordena ascendente y descendente de una vez.. eso es lo que necesito hacer ...

Comment: @JulioPerez, eso se te explico en tu anterior pregunta, se te dijo que enlazadas un bindingSource a tu datagrid

Comment: Antes lo hacia así y funcionaba perfecto..                 DataSet ds = DUnidad_Dian.ConsultaTodo();
                dt = ds.Tables[0];
                dgvUnidadDian.DataSource = dt;
Pero ahora me estoy cambiando a linq y tengo ese problema...

Comment: @JulioPerez, revisa bien las respuestas que se te dieron en tu anterior pregunta

Comment: Amigo Japv - lo probé como me dijiste pero no me funciono..

Comment: Enlazarse un bindingSource al datagrid?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126330/discussion-between-japv-and-julio-perez).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para usar el **método** **Sort** de un **DataGrid** este debe estar enlazado a un **IBindingList**, los **DataTable** implementan esta interfaz por eso cuando un **DataGrid** está enlazado con un **DataTable** puedes usar el **método** **Sort**, pero una consulta en **Linq** no devuelve un tipo de dato **IBindingList**, por lo que la forma de hacerlo usando **Linq** es diferente:

Primero tener en cuenta que en el **evento** **Load** del formulario debes cargar el **DataGrid** ordenado por defecto con el campo que desees, tu **método** **CargarGrillaLoad** se mantiene tal como lo tienes hasta ahora:

```
public List<EUsuario> CargarGrillaLoad()
{
  using (ContaAITEntities bdDatos = new ContaAITEntities())
  {
     List<EUsuario> Consulta = (from e in bdDatos.Usuario
                                orderby e.Cod_Usuario
                                select new EUsuario
                                {
                                   Cod_Usuario = e.Cod_Usuario,
                                   Nom_Usuario = e.Nom_Usuario,
                                   Doc_Usuario = e.Doc_usuario,
                                   Estado = e.Estado == "A" ? "Activo" : "Inactivo"
                                }).ToList();

       return Consulta;                                           
   }
}
```

Y entonces en tu **evento Load** para llenar el **DataGrid** debes poner:

```
datagrid.DataSource = CargarGrillaLoad();
```

Y por supuesto debes quitar del **evento Load** todo el código que usa el **método** **Sort** para ordenar ya que no hace falta.

Ahora bien para ordenar por una columna específica cuando des click encima de su encabezado debes hacer lo siguiente:

Primero asumo que tu **DataGrid** va a tener cuatro columnas en este orden (**Codigo**, **NombreUsuario**, **DocumentoUsuario** y **Estado**).

En **C#** las colecciones inician en **0**, por lo que la columna **Codigo** estará en la posición **0**, la columna **NombreUsuario** será la posición **1**, la columna **DocumentoUsuario** la posición **2** y la columna **Estado** la posición **3**.

Entonces vas a crear dos métodos uno para ordenar ascendentemente y otro descendentemente cuando des clic en el encabezado de una columna.

```
public void OrdenarGridAscendente(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{               
   List<EUsuario> lista = (from e in bdDatos.Usuario
                           select new EUsuario
                           {
                              Cod_Usuario = e.Cod_Usuario,
                              Nom_Usuario = e.Nom_Usuario,
                              Doc_Usuario = e.Doc_usuario,
                              Estado = e.Estado == "A" ? "Activo" : "Inactivo"
                           }).ToList();

   if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Codigo
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(l => l.Cod_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)//NombreUsuario
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(l => l.Nom_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)//DocumentoUsuario
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(l => l.Doc_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)//Estado
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderBy(l => l.Estado).ToList();
   }            
}
```

Y descendentemente sería:

```
public void OrdenarGridDescendente(DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{               
   List<EUsuario> lista = (from e in bdDatos.Usuario
                           select new EUsuario
                           {
                              Cod_Usuario = e.Cod_Usuario,
                              Nom_Usuario = e.Nom_Usuario,
                              Doc_Usuario = e.Doc_usuario,
                              Estado = e.Estado == "A" ? "Activo" : "Inactivo"
                           }).ToList();

   if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)//Codigo
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(l => l.Cod_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)//NombreUsuario
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(l => l.Nom_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)//DocumentoUsuario
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(l => l.Doc_Usuario).ToList();
   }
   else if (e.ColumnIndex == 3)//Estado
   {
      datagrid.DataSource = lista.OrderByDescending(l => l.Estado).ToList();
   }            
}
```

Estos métodos reciben como parámetro un tipo de dato **DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs** que nos va a permitir determinar sobre que encabezado de columna dimos click.

Lo primero que se hace en estos métodos es hacer una consulta general para obtener la lista completa de usuarios y posteriormente se irá preguntando sobre el índice de columna que se dió clic para determinar porque criterio se va a ordenar y atendiendo a ese criterio se muestra la información en el **DataGrid** ordenada.

Entonces iríamos al **evento** **ColumnHeaderMouseClick** que será el encargado de capturar el clic sobre el encabezado de las columnas y pondríamos:

```
if (descendente)
{
   OrdenarGridAscendente(e);                           
}
else 
{
   OrdenarGridDescendente(e);
}

descendente = !descendente;
```

En este evento se ordena el **DataGrid** llamando los métodos que previamente habíamos creado, es decir si actualmente está ordenado el **DataGrid** descendentemente, pues se ordenará ascendentemente, y si está ordenado ascendentemente pues se ordenará descendentemente, de esta forma se va alternando el orden.

La **variable** **descendente** es de tipo **booleano** y es una **variable global** que se inicializa en el **evento Load** como:

```
descendente = true;
```

Esta solución puede mejorarse muchísimo más, lo importante es que te lleves la idea y después con el tiempo la mejores.

Comment: Muchas gracias..,.